# Checking for error message from os.Remove

Tags: go

What's the most idiomatic way to check error messages? My use case is that in `err := os.Remove(path)`, I consider a success either:

A) if `err == nil`

or

B) if `err != nil` but the error is thrown because the file was not found.

any other error should cause the removal to retry. Currently I've wrapped this in a `for { ... }` loop and am checking:

```
if err == nil || strings.Contains(err.Error(), "no such file") {
    // Success
} else {
    // Fail
}
```

Since [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Remove) say:

> If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

I don't think there's a way to check by type assertion. Am I missing something fundamental? My error handling in Go has always felt somewhat slapdash.

Comment: You can use `os.IsNotExist(err)`

Comment: @AlexGuerra I had no idea that was a thing. Of course I should do that lol...

Comment: Note that there plenty more errors (if not most) that can't be "fixed" by retrying, such as insufficient permissions, so don't retry indefinitely.

Comment: @Peter fair, but in my situation there's little fear of that. My three failure scenarios are that the remote machine is offline, that the file doesn't exist, and that the file is in use (hooray Windows)

Answer (score 3):

I just dealt with this the other day. An error from `os.Remove()` will be `syscall.ENOENT` if the file did not exist.

So you can use logic like this:

```
if err != nil {
    e, ok := err.(*os.PathError)
    if ok && e.Err == syscall.ENOENT {
        // The file didn't exist
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    } else {
        // Error other than syscall.ENOENT
    }
}
```

Of course, as shown in another answer, `os.IsNotExist()` is simple and idiomatic. Wish I'd seen that before today.

Answer (score 2):

The "type" `error` is an interface. Interfaces don't have an concrete type. To get the type of the value you could use a type assertion or a type switch:

```
// Type assertion
_, ok := err.(*PathError)

// Type switch
switch err.(type) {
case *PathError:
    // You know the type now
}
```

This is an idiomatic way to find out of which type an error is. As in the comments specified there is already a function inside the os package which does this for you (https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist)

Comment: Well, I think I like `os.IsNotExist()` better. Thanks!